# How should you initialize a cube map array in OpenGL 4.5?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

Say I want a cube map array of 10 cube maps, each of 2048x2048 resolution and with only 1 mipmap level.

I am currently trying to initialize is as:

```
    glGenTextures(1, &shadowMapArray);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, shadowMapArray);
    glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY,1, GL_R8, 2048, 2048, 10);
```

Which returns a GL_INVALID_VALUE enumerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [cube map arrays](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Cubemap_Array_Texture), the depth is not the number of array layers. It is the number of layer-faces, which must be a multiple of 6. So if you want 10 cube map array layers, you ask for 60 layer faces.

Every OpenGL API that deals in cube map arrays takes layer-face indices/counts, not layers.